# How to create non-overlapping intervals in the legend?

Tags: qgis, legend

So I am trying to create a legend where the entries are, for example, like this:

- 1.1 - 2.0
- 2.1 - 3.0
- 3.1 - 4.0

as opposed to like this:

- 1.1 - 2.1
- 2.1 - 3.1
- 3.1 - 4.1

I essentially don't want the upperbound of one interval to be the same as the lowerbound of the next interval. I know I can do this by setting the Legend Format to "%11 - %20" but in that case, I would end up with two digits after the decimal, where as I only want one digit after the decimal.

Comment: I don't think that you can..with the first example there is a gap between 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: In case that one value is exactly 2.1 (lower bound of one class and upper bound of another), how exactly does QGIS deal with that?

Comment: It goes with the first class.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely worth keeping in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @NajS With that in mind, you could make it clear how your intervals deal with extreme values by means of legend labels. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132775/how-does-the-qgis-construct-class-intervals/132833#132833

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use my favourite **Rule-based** style instead of Graduated:

[image: Rule-based style]

It may require a bit of work in setting the rules but you have much greater control in terms of customisation (atleast I think so!).

Hope this helps!