# Some features are not rendering when applying graduated styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, style, features, rendering

I am trying to style a polygon layer as graduated according to a specific field of the polygon shapefile in QGIS.

I selected equal interval or equal count and then sort but when I clicked <kbd>Ok</kbd> one feature is not rendered. Its value equals the upper limit of the upper class. This occurred with the other types of styling like pretty jerks too. What can be a problem?

Comment: Floating point numbers? Possibly the value does not exactly equal the upper bound, and you are hitting a rounding / representation error in the data.

Comment: Yes, the lower limit of the lower class has value 0.000042906 and the value of the feature which is not rendered is smaller than that. But, when I increase the precision and the lower value of the lower class is equal with the value of the feature, it is not rendered too. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be described in this post: [How does the QGIS construct class intervals?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132775/how-does-the-qgis-construct-class-intervals)